# Unknown column '2' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

```
select count(distinct(vw_SIPMIP.product_id)) from vw_SIPMIP , sp_mip_rule  
where 
vw_SIPMIP.product_id not in (select a.product_id from vw_non_SIPMIP a) 
and sp_mip_rule.id = vw_SIPMIP.id 
and sp_mip_rule.createdby != '_IMPORT' limit 1
```

I am keep getting this error

Comment: There is no "2" and no ORDER clause in the query you show.

Comment: I know thats the worst part.... I have no clue where it is getting the "Order" Clause from.....

Comment: My guess - the `order by` is inside of your view - `vw_SIPMIP` or `vw_non_SIPMIP`.  Can you post the code for those views?

Comment: Did you try to execute the query with the command line ?

Comment: No i did not try it on command line... I will try now

Comment: the view is too big to be posted here..... but there is order by clause in one of the view.....

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is incorrect on the distinct...  By using the  (parens), it is thinking Distinct is a function and expecting the inner value as a parameter to pass and get a value back... what you want is...  Additionally, since you have no other columns you are returning, you don't need a limit one... COUNT(*) or COUNT(DISTINCT SomeColumn) will ALWAYS return a single row all by itself... no group by needed.

```
select count(distinct vw_SIPMIP.product_id) YourDistinctCount
   from vw_SIPMIP, 
        sp_mip_rule
   where  vw_SIPMIP.product_id not in (select a.product_id from vw_non_SIPMIP a)  
     and sp_mip_rule.id = vw_SIPMIP.id  
     and sp_mip_rule.createdby != '_IMPORT'
```